# How to get data from n:m tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I have these [tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnXLH.png) in my MariaDB database

In table `questNpc` i added `npc` with ID 50 to `quest` with ID 46.
I would like to get all `NPCs` which are not assigned to quest.

I can't figure out what the query sql should look like.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE npc
    (`id` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO npc
    (`id`)
VALUES
    (1),
    (2),
    (3),
    (4)
;

CREATE TABLE guestNpc
    (`guestnpc_id` int, `npc_id` int)    
;
  
INSERT INTO guestNpc
    (`guestnpc_id`, `npc_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 4)
;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM npc WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT npc_id FROM guestNpc);
```

| id |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 3 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3ZPa6Wig8MAjL1mnBrMuq6/0)